# Creating/listing subfolder with Vimeo API

Tags: c#, .net, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying vimeo API using C#.
I succeeded in creating and listing vimeo folder with vimeo API.

However, I cannot find how to create subfolders and list subfolder items with API
I have read official documents but I could not find any related APIs.
I also tested my video page at vimeo site but I can create the folders with the same name.

I have read vimeo folder was "project" originally.
I suspect that vimeo API may not support the subfolder system yet.

Is there any way to handle the subfolder with Vimeo API?

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, this is now handled in the recommended Vimeo .Net/C# tool (https://www.nuget.org/packages/VimeoDotNet/).  It now handles the optional parameter in the `CreateVideoFolder()` method for the parent folder URI.  See the answer below for how to structure that URI string.

Answer (score 4):

Vimeo's API documentation for **Create a Folder** is missing the important but optional parameter **parent_folder_uri** which allows you to create a sub-folder under a parent folder.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders?version=3.4#_essentials

Use the same endpoint as a regular create folder request.

`POST /users/{user_id}/projects`

However, in addition to the **name** parameter include **parent_folder_uri** formatted like below.

```
{ 
  name: "My Subfolder", 
  parent_folder_uri: "/users/{userId}/projects/{parent_project_id}"
}
```

It's a strange implementation. I'm not sure why you have to pass the parent folder's URL as a string instead of just the project_id but it works so I'm not complaining

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Folder First, then you take the TopLevel Uri Folder from the Json Response!, and use this Folder Uri to create an subfolder.

```
let endpoint = URL(string: "https://api.vimeo.com/me/folders")!
var request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
 request.httpMethod = "POST"

 let headers: [String: String] = [
  "Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4",
  "Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  ]
  request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
  let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "name": "subFolderName",
        "parent_folder_uri": parentFolderUri
    ]
     if let bodyData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters) {
        request.httpBody = bodyData
      } else {
        // Handle JSON serialization error
        print("Error serializing JSON.")
       }
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data , response , error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: SubFolder: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let data = data {
            if let stringResponse = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { 
                print("stringResponseSubFolder: \(stringResponse)")
            }
        }
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("httpResponse: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    }.resume()
```